# Solutions of AX=B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to determinate if this system has one solution and infinite solutions.

$AX=B$, with $A_{m\times n}$, $X_{n\times p}$ and $B_{m\times p}$

So i don't know if I can use the rank of A to determinate this, however i don't know if A is a square matrix. So if A is column row rank then:

$AX=0 $ implies  $X=A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}0=0$

so it has one solution, but what happens if the system has infinite solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution set to $Ax=b$, when $x \in \mathbb{K}^n,b \in \mathbb{K}^m$, is always either empty (if no solution exists) or an affine space of dimension equal to the nullity of $A$ (if some solution exists). The nullity of $A$ is $n-r$ where $r$ is the rank (this is the "rank-nullity theorem").

For $AX=B$ where $X$ and $B$ are now matrices, you just apply the previous statement to each column of $B$ separately (since $AX=B$ is really just $p$ systems $Ax_k=b_k$).